# Build error : BUG ! exception in phase 'instruction selection ' in source set

Tags: spring, grails, groovy

I have created a domain class named Curr_Stud_Info.groovy

```
package ads2

import gorm.logical.delete.LogicalDelete

class Curr_Stud_Info implements LogicalDelete{

    static constraints = {
        current_std nullable: false
        division nullable: false
        roll_no nullable: false
    }

    static belongsTo = [student : Student]
    static mapping = {student column: id}   //this is needed only  in belongs to methods for giving relationship  to different column

    Integer current_std
    Character division
    Integer roll_no    
}
```

during building this project i am getting error in it's specs file Curr_Stud_InfoSpec.groovy which is

```
package ads2

import grails.testing.gorm.DomainUnitTest
import spock.lang.Specification

class Curr_Stud_InfoSpec extends Specification implements DomainUnitTest<Curr_Stud_Info> {

    def setup() {
    }

    def cleanup() {
    }

    void "test something"() {
        expect:"fix me"
            true == false
    }
}
```

which is grails generated.
error is

> Error:Groovyc: While compiling tests of ads2.ads2.test: BUG! exception
>   in phase 'instruction selection' in source unit
>   '/home/pathpanchal/PROJECT/ads2/ads2/src/test/groovy/ads2/Curr_Stud_InfoSpec.groovy'
>   Type is null. Most probably you let a transform reuse existing
>   ClassNodes with generics information, that is now used in a wrong
>   context.  at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v5.Java5.configureType(Java5.java:125)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v5.Java5.configureTypeArguments(Java5.java:186)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v5.Java5.configureParameterizedType(Java5.java:166)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v5.Java5.configureType(Java5.java:117)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v5.Java5.makeClassNode(Java5.java:439)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v5.Java5.configureClassNode(Java5.java:370)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.lazyClassInit(ClassNode.java:280)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.getInterfaces(ClassNode.java:375)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.declaresInterface(ClassNode.java:981)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.implementsInterface(ClassNode.java:961)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.transform.stc.StaticTypeCheckingVisitor.getResultType(StaticTypeCheckingVisitor.java:3717)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.transform.stc.StaticTypeCheckingVisitor.visitBinaryExpression(StaticTypeCheckingVisitor.java:716)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.BinaryExpression.visit(BinaryExpression.java:51)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.ast.CodeVisitorSupport.visitExpressionStatement(CodeVisitorSupport.java:122)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitExpressionStatement(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:196)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.ExpressionStatement.visit(ExpressionStatement.java:42)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitClassCodeContainer(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:104)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitConstructorOrMethod(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:115)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.transform.stc.StaticTypeCheckingVisitor.visitConstructorOrMethod(StaticTypeCheckingVisitor.java:1963)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitMethod(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:126)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.transform.stc.StaticTypeCheckingVisitor.startMethodInference(StaticTypeCheckingVisitor.java:2318)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.transform.stc.StaticTypeCheckingVisitor.visitMethod(StaticTypeCheckingVisitor.java:2277)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.transform.sc.StaticCompilationVisitor.visitMethod(StaticCompilationVisitor.java:224)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.transform.sc.StaticCompileTransformation.visit(StaticCompileTransformation.java:80)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.transform.ASTTransformationVisitor.visitClass(ASTTransformationVisitor.java:152)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.transform.ASTTransformationVisitor$2.call(ASTTransformationVisitor.java:196)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToPrimaryClassNodes(CompilationUnit.java:1087)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:624)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:602)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:579)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.groovy.compiler.rt.GroovyCompilerWrapper.compile(GroovyCompilerWrapper.java:62)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.groovy.compiler.rt.DependentGroovycRunner.runGroovyc(DependentGroovycRunner.java:119)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.jetbrains.groovy.compiler.rt.GroovycRunner.intMain2(GroovycRunner.java:90)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.groovy.InProcessGroovyc.runGroovycInThisProcess(InProcessGroovyc.java:160)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.groovy.InProcessGroovyc.lambda$runGroovyc$0(InProcessGroovyc.java:89)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

i dont know why this error is occuring and how to solve it ??pls help

Comment: I assume this is grails. What version?

Comment: grails 3.3.9 @tim_yates